# OpenGL, how to get the Zdepth value, from the coordinates of a point

Tags: opengl, math, matrix

I know how to do the opposite way. (Read the z-deph from the buffer and then use the unPjoject):

```
(...)
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, depth)
gluUnProject(x, y, depth, view_matrix, projection_matrix, viewport, world_x, world_y, world_z)

return world_x, world_y, world_z
```

But how can I do otherwise?
I have the `world_x`, `world_y` and `world_z` values, how a get the `depth`.

Answer (score 0):

We need to transform the vector to 2d and get the `w component`

```
prj = perspective_matrix * Vector((world_x, world_y, world_z, 1.0f))
```

Now we need to normalize `z component` (The Z value is between -1 and 1)

```
z_depth = prj.z / proj.w
```

For some stupid reason, OpenGL requires that it should be moved to the [0,1] range

```
z_depth = (z_depth + 1) / 2
```

There it is